# asp.NET MVC create chart dynamically

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, charts, asp.net-ajax

I need help with creating chart dynamically from data I previously loaded from xml file.

View:

```
using prvniAplikace.Models
@using Chart.Mvc.ComplexChart;
@using Chart.Mvc.Extensions

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("LoadFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post,
                                                     new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    <div class="form-group" align="left">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">Load File</label>
        <input type="file" accept=".tcx" class="form-control-file" name="exampleInputFile" id="exampleInputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" align="left">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="tlacitko">Display</button>
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;

namespace prvniAplikace.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LoadFile(HttpPostedFileBase exampleInputFile)
        {


            if (exampleInputFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(exampleInputFile.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
                exampleInputFile.SaveAs(path);

                TempData["message-success"] = "Soubor byl nahran";

                string xmlFile = Server.MapPath(fileName);

                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(path);
                XmlNodeList nodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("HeartRateBpm");
                XmlNodeList nodes2 = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Time");

                List<int> hodnotyT = new List<int>();
                List<string> hodnotyCasu = new List<string>();

                foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
                {
                    int hodnota = Int32.Parse(node["Value"].InnerText);
                    hodnotyT.Add(hodnota);
                }

                foreach (XmlNode node in nodes2)
                {
                    string value = node.ChildNodes[0].Value;
                    hodnotyCasu.Add(value);
                }

                List<DateTime> casy = new List<DateTime>();
                string format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";

                foreach (string value in hodnotyCasu)
                {
                    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(value, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    casy.Add(dt);
                }

                DateTime dt1 = casy[0];
                List<TimeSpan> casyGraf = new List<TimeSpan>();


                foreach  (DateTime date in casy)
                {
                    TimeSpan rozdil = date - dt1;
                    casyGraf.Add(rozdil);
                }

                List<string> casyGrafText = new List<string>();

                foreach (TimeSpan time in casyGraf)
                {
                    string casovac = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
                    casyGrafText.Add(casovac);
                }

                ViewBag.ListCasy = casyGrafText;
                ViewBag.ListTep = hodnotyT;

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

So far I have a method in controller that I call on a button click. That method is loading xml file and process the data. In my current output I have two Lists with data and I need to display a line chart from the data under my current webpage. i am using a library chart.js right now.

My view and I want to display the chart under it:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr0ZS.png)

Any ideas on how can I do it?

Comment: You are going to need more clarity here. What kind of chart? What does your view currently look like?

Comment: I edited the text, I want to have a line chart

Comment: From a high level, I would say you will probably want to use Razor to render out the html elements that you will need for your graph, and put the ids and classes you will need on them. From there I would probably use D3 to render the graph using those html elements. https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery